# FullCalendar React header custom buttons not showing

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to add some icons to the header as buttons, I've tried using both bootstrap and fontawesome as mentioned in the docs but I get an empty square instead of the icon. When using the bootstrap theme I get 'undefined', when using the standard I get the below.

Here's my code:

```
const customButtons = { 
    custom1: { 
        icon: "fa-times", 
        click: function() { 
            alert('test');
        }
    }
} 

<CustomCalendar
       customCalendarRef={customCalendarRef}
       select={(e: any) => processClick(e)}
       customButtons={customButtons}
       themeSystem="standard"
       header={{
             right: '',
             center: '',
             left: 'prev,next today custom1'
       }}
/>
```

Result:

[image]

How can I show an icon as a button in the header?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using fullcalendar in my react app so I've tried using your code. First there's one thing you forgot, wich is fontawesome icons also needs the "fa" class, so the correct would be `fa fa-times`, not only `fa-times`.

But then there's another issue which is the icon comes with custom fullcalendar classes when rendered:

[image]

So a solution you might use is to add this to your css somewhere:

```
.fc-icon.fa {
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome !important;
}
```

It worked for me:

[image]

**Edited:**

The string of the fontawesome classes should start with a blank space otherwise the 'fa' class will concatenate with the fullcalendar class. So: `icon: ' fa fa-times'`

Comment: I've added fa to the icon name and added the css, now I get a small white square inside the button. When I inspect the class name I get something slightly different to you as well, I get `fc-icon fc-icon-fa fa-times`. Your fa is separated from icon. The thing is the other icons such as the left and right arrows work, but this custom one won't. So I thought maybe I was missing a css sheet but then the arrows wouldn't work either right?

Comment: I still get the same white square if I were to target the generated css classes directly `.fc-icon.fc-icon-fa.fa-times`

Comment: hey Nats, I forgot to tell you the string of the fontawesome classes should start with a blank space otherwise the 'fa' class will concatenate with the fullcalendar class. So: `icon: ' fa fa-times'`

Comment: I've tried this but I still get the small white square. I have noticed this error in the browser however: `calendar:1 GET chrome-extension://hfapbcheiepjppjbnkphkmegjlipojba/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. It may not be able to access the fonts files?

Comment: Are you using a specific stylesheet?

Comment: Is the app available anyhwere I can debug it? But yes, you are probably missing the font-awesome fonts. Are you using icons elsewhere in the app? Can you see them normally?

Comment: Nope, I'm not using a specific stylesheet. I have the fullcalendar css and the font-awesome css and then my other stuff which is not related to the calendar rendering

Comment: I swapped out the link I was using and it's now showing! Using the boostrap cdn link for font-awesome worked. I had been using the one specified in the full calendar docs. Thanks a lot for taking the time to look into this :)